Integration of flutter application into linphone codebase
Actually, I want to integrate my Flutter app with the existing linphone (VoIP) project (it is open source)  and while I am trying to do this I am getting multiple errors. If any of you know the process and steps then please help me.
I am trying to merge two existing mobile application code to build a new mobile application. When I tried to do this by making a module of my application and add into linphone application directory when I ran the project the app crashed and there were a lot of errors.
If anyone has any documentation on that or any source link then please help me

Do you need to add calling functionality into the own app or own UI into the existing app?
Linphone has plugin https://pub.dev/packages/linphone_flutter_plugin, which you can add to the own Flutter app and create UI/business logic around it. As similar and alternative solution you can check Siprix - https://github.com/siprix/FlutterPlugin.
